# Was ist das Wort oder die Phrase, die von deutschen Mathematikern für "ungefähr gleich" oder ≈ verwendet wird?

Tags: mathematics

Was ist das Wort oder die Phrase, die von deutschen Mathematikern für "ungefähr gleich" oder `≈` verwendet wird?

Answer (score 5):

**Vorbemerkung**

Das Symbol `≈` hat in der Mathematik keine standardisierte Bedeutung, sondern wird **kontextabhängig** benutzt.

In der Algebra ist es als "isomorph" zu verstehen (isomorphe Gruppen, isomorphe Körper, isomorphe Vektorräume, usw.).

In der Topologie bedeutet es "homöomorph" (homöomorphe topologische Räume).

**`≈` im numerischen Kontext**

Die Bedeutung ist "ungefähr gleich" oder "gerundet". Das betrachte ich als *best practice*. Ich bezweifle jedoch, dass deutsche Mathematiker hier eine völlig einheitliche Sprechweise pflegen. In planetmakers Antwort findet man andere Varianten.

Kaum verwunderlich dürfte es jedoch sein, dass das Deutsches Institut für Normung e. V. (DIN) eine Norm formuliert hat, nämlich

> [DIN 1302 : Allgemeine mathematische Zeichen und Begriffe - [1999-12-00]](https://katalog.slub-dresden.de/id/211-DE45852254)

Das Inhaltverzeichnis findet man [hier](https://www.din.de/de/mitwirken/normenausschuesse/natg/veroeffentlichungen/wdc-beuth:din21:20122828). Zitat aus [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIN_1302):

> **Pragmatische Zeichen**
> Bei den pragmatischen Zeichen handelt es sich nicht um mathematische Zeichen im engeren Sinn. Ihre Bedeutung wird erst durch den Benutzer und eine Anwendungssituation von Fall zu Fall präzisiert. Beispiele:
> x ≈ y (ungefähr gleich), ...

Siehe auch [hier](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gleichheitszeichen).

Answer (score 3):

Genau das, was Du schreibst. Daneben gibt es noch eine Reihe Alternativen, die ähnlich gebräuchlich und auch nicht weniger richtig oder weniger professionell sind:

- X ist ungefähr gleich Y
- X ist ungefähr Y
- X ist in etwa (gleich) Y
- X ist annähernd (gleich) Y
- X ist angenähert (gleich) Y

in manchen Kontexten, wo es eine Rundung angibt, ggf. auch

- X ist rund Y
- X ist gerundet Y

Comment: Oder: *X ist in etwa (gleich) Y.*

Comment: Thanks indeed. I edited that into the answer.

Comment: Oder: *angenähert / annähernd* gleich

Comment: Also thanks. I amended the answer with that, too